# connected and compact but not closed?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

Take $A= f(B)$ contained in a topological space $X$, where $B= \{(x,y)\in {\Bbb R}^2| 2\leq x^2+ y^2\leq 6\}$ and $f:{\Bbb R}^2 \to X$ is a continous map.
How this one is not closed but is compact? It is compact and connected. But when it is compact why not it is closed then?

Comment: Compact implies closed in hausdorff spaces, not in general. Hint: consider a finite topology and note that one point is always connected.

Comment: Please improve your question. It's not entirely clear what you mean and what you're asking. There's nothing odd with being compact and connected - take $X=\{a, b\}$ with the topology $\{\emptyset, X\}$, now $\{a\}$ is a compact, connected set, but it's neither open nor closed.

Comment: @Noah hits the point. You do not know what kind of topology on $X$, so it may happen in $X$.

Answer (score 1):

B is a compact, closed, connected annulus. By continuity f(B)=A is compact and connected. However to guarantee f(B) is closed we would need the function f to map closed sets to closed sets, which is not a consequence of continuity. Consider X to be the indiscrete topology on R^2, then any map is continuous so you can take f to be the identity map and B is not closed in the indiscrete topology.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the case where $X=\{1,2\}$ where $\{1\}$ is open but $\{2\}$ is not open. (This is called Sierpinski space.) Suppose $A= f(B)=\{1\}$. Then $A$ is not closed in $X.$

Comment: I don't understand completely.

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz.  Sierpinski space is a 2-point space $X=\{1,2\} $ with exactly 3 open subsets: $\emptyset, \{1\},$ and $X$.  And exactly 3 closed sets : $\emptyset, \{2\},$ and $X$...  If $T$ is any non-empty space and $ f(t)=1$ for all $t\in T$ then $f:T\to X$ is continuous. But $f(T)=\{1\}$ is not closed in $X$, although $\{1\}$ is compact because it is finite.... A compact subset of a Hausdorff space must be closed, but this is not true for all non-Hausdorff spaces.